# Confiusing matrix, identificators and streams

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, pdfbox, adobe-reader

I've just signed a document using Acrobat Reader.

I've got that result:

[image]

Now I have these questions:

1. what does  `q, q` means in the stream?
2. I have matrix `[48, 0, 0, 17.5200043, 12, 27.2400055]`. What does it mean, and how to calculate that? I'm going to create PDF by hand, and I'm interested in that. `im0` is the name of Image (I have Visible signature in PDF).
3. Then I have `Do Q Q`. What does it mean?
4. Also, I have `n0` XObject too. That stream is `% DSBlank`. Is it important? What is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start reading the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), you will not get far by asking questions here about each pdf operator. 
1. The q operator saves the graphics state, the Q operator restores it. In your context 'q q' is redundant.
2. The matrix sets the image (/Im0 that follows) position and size. Elements 1 and 4 of the matrix are image size, elements 5 and 6 and image position (bottom left corner). This is a simplistic explanation, you should read the PDF specification to see how the trasnformation matrix works. 
3. The Do operator paints the /Im0 XObject (your image).
4. % starts a comment line and % DSBlank is just a comment.

PS: The application you use for exploring the PDF structure is developed by the company I work for :)